# Solr search server: How to strip off HTML entities from content to be indexed

Tags: solr, django-haystack

I am newbie to Solr and have no skills in Java, so maybe I am missing something… I am trying to get Solr to strip off HTML from content, using the following CharFilter:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory

This is how I am including it into my schema.xml:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<fields>
  <field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
</fields>
```

If I query using the analyzer on the Solr admin panel for "d'Hèrcules", I get a match (see  field):

```
<doc>
<long name="comment_count">0</long>
<str name="ct_model_name">theatre</str>
<str name="django_ct">timeout.work</str>
<str name="django_id">2535</str>
<bool name="family">false</bool>
<long name="hits">0</long>
<str name="id">timeout.work.2535</str>
<str name="name">Les aventures d'Hèrcules</str>
<arr name="parent_sections">
<str>Escena</str>
</arr>
<long name="rating">0</long>
<bool name="recommended">false</bool>
<arr name="sections">
<str>Escena - Infantil</str>
</arr>
<str name="text">
Les aventures d&#39;Hèrcules Jordi Andújar &lt;p&gt;Prepareu-vos per viatjar a l’antiga Grècia on coneixereu l’heroi més gran de tots els temps: l’Hèrcules. De viatge cap a l’Olimp, l’heroi viurà les més increïbles aventures, lluitarà amb bèsties ferotges i perillosos monstres, i s’enfrontarà a la maldat de la temible deessa Hera. Per a tota la família&lt;/p&gt;
</str>
...
</doc>
```

but I need to match by searching the non-HTML-entity form: e.g. in this case, would be "l'Hèrcules" (note the single quote).

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I am using django-haystack, if this info is useful in any way.

Thanks in advance,

Hector

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's me, but I really don't get what's going wrong and what you want to achieve. Could you please clarify your question?

Comment: @javanna well, basically I want to search for "d'Hèrcules" and match the data containing it... The problem is that the source content has HTML entities (in this case it has "d&#39;Hèrcules") and when I index it, Solr is storing it "as is", so I only can match when I query with exactly the same string (i.e. "d&#39;Hèrcules")

Comment: Where does this HTML exist? In file-system? You can "POST-in" HTML or any kind of rich documents (doc, pdf) with http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler . It will extract the text from the HTML and index it for you.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt notice that (part of) your issue was non-latin characters. YMMV then :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing well on Solr side, the only thing you should notice is that there's a difference between what Solr stores and what Solr indexes. Solr stores data as they are without modifying anything, while through the analyzer chain you can change the way Solr indexes data.
So you are actually telling Solr to strip any html tag from the index and to replace html entities with related characters, but Solr will always return them as you submitted them.

You can search for `d'Hèrcules` or `d&#39;Hèrcules` and you should have the same results, since you have the `HtmlStripCharFilterFactory` fired even at query time, so you are basically submitting the same query for `d'Hèrcules` in both cases because `&#39;` is converted to `'`.

Your search for `l'Hèrcules` makes me think that the unescaped character between `l` and `Hercules` in your document isn't `'` but something that looks really similar. I think you should check this.

Comment: I agree, if you do not want the HTML to appear at all, you will need to strip it out in another process prior to sending to Solr or parse it out after you get the response back from Solr. We had a similar issue and choose to remove the HTML markup prior to indexing the content.